# Gridview TemplateField checkbox postback behavior in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0, gridview, autopostback

I have GridView inside UpdatePanel and UpdateMode of the UpdatePanel is set to conditional.

Gridview contains asp:CheckBox as TemplateField and rest of the columns are boundfields which are dynamically created.
Checbox AutoPostBack is set to true and I update a datatable (which is inside session) based on checkbox value.

Here is markup:

```
<asp:GridView ID="ObjList" runat="server"  CssClass="ObjList" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="ObjList_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateSelectButton="false" AllowPaging="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="&nbsp">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox AutoPostBack="true" ID="chkAll" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="HeaderChk_Changed" />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="LinkNumIndexHead" runat="server" Value="-1" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox AutoPostBack="true" ID="chkRow" runat="server" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Selection")%>'
                    OnCheckedChanged="ChkRow_OnCheckChange" />                                                 
        </ItemTemplate>                                                
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

**In Deployed version only:**
Whenever user click 2 or more checkboxes in fast speed. Postback of first checkbox fires and rest of checkboxes get unchecked. How can I control this behavior?

**When Local IIS is running:**
Postback of every checkbox fires.

In Firebug debugging it is noticed that Postback of first checkbox takes quite a time.
Please tell me how can I avoid this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<asp:GridView ID="ObjList" runat="server" CssClass="ObjList" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    OnRowDataBound="ObjList_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateSelectButton="false" AllowPaging="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="&nbsp">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox AutoPostBack="true" ID="chkAll" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="HeaderChk_Changed" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="LinkNumIndexHead" runat="server" Value="-1" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox AutoPostBack="true" ID="chkRow" runat="server" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Selection")%>'
                            OnCheckedChanged="ChkRow_OnCheckChange" />
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: thank you for reply. DataItem is not recognized and compilation error occurs after adding templates into updatepanels.